# Toggling dynamically created checkbox in react

Tags: javascript, checkbox, reactjs

I have created a table dynamically in react with some fields and a checkbox in each row. Now In the column header I have a checkbox. When I click the checkbox I want all the rows checkbox to be selected. Also now if I click any checkbox, that should toggle its state.

Till now I am able to generate the dynamic rows in the table and delete individual rows.

**Table Headers**

```
                           <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="table-responsive">  
                                        <table id="mytable" class="table table-bordred table-striped">  
                                            <thead>  
                                                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" onChange={this.checkAll}/></th>
                                                <th>Id</th>
                                                <th>Id1</th>
                                                <th>Id2</th>
                                                <th>Email</th>
                                                <th>Edit</th>  
                                                <th>Delete</th>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody>{users}</tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Function to add new user

```
addUserState =(dat) => {
        let data = JSON.parse(dat);
        let id = this.randomPassword(32);

        let newElement = null
        newElement = <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis"/></td>
                    <td class="userId">{id}</td>
                    <td class="id1">{data.payload.id1}</td>
                    <td class="id2">{data.payload.id2}</td>
                    <td class="userEmail">{data.payload.email}</td>
                    <td><p data-placement="top" title="Edit"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></p></td>
                    <td><p data-placement="top" title="Delete"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" onClick={this.deleteUser.bind(this, id)}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></p></td>
                    </tr>
        this.setState({users: this.state.users.concat([newElement])});
    }
```

CheckAllfunction:

```
checkAll = (e) => {
        let length = this.state.users.length;
        if(e.target.checked) {
            for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                console.log(this.state.users[i]);
                //Do what here
            }
        }

    }
```

one possible way I find is to associate a **checked state** property with each of the checkboxes that I create but it will be difficult to manage, since I will be performing **CRUD** operations on the rows.

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: You need to create new react component for table row and handle state in this new component. In this case you will be able to notify all the components-rows that it need to be checked. Also you will be able to get the state of row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkboxes are about toggling data state of variable which is limited to true/false value. There is no need to read it's value from DOM, React offers you much cleaner way.

```
toggleCheckbox() {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
}
```

Please, see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/40345/). It contains full example with code handling your use case on data level.

Comment: In your fiddle for every attribute row you have used a checked property defined in state. My rows are dynamically created, meaning I can have around 100+ rows and I should not use a checked property separately for each checkbox.

Comment: Oh yes, you definitely should store `checked` state for every row - or at least you should store indexes/IDs of "checked" rows and update rendering & state logic behind `checked` attribute of each row

Comment: Is there no efficient way to solve this problem. I don't want to end up using this.

Comment: Why do you consider it inefficient? I consider it no-brainer for React. This is what React is made for.

Comment: I need to add rows dynamically. But I can't quite figure out how do I do that. Can you edit you fiddle for that, as I want to use you style of code. I find it much better than mine. I will accept the answer as soon as I implement it

Comment: Thank you so much for a complete answer.